# Javascript Variables not Outputting correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason when I try to output a group of concatenated strings and variables, the output I get this output:

```
Arr! I, function (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)} have plunderedundefined gold 
doubloons and sold them for a total of $NaN time to buy me a new cannon!
```

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
    <head>

        <title>Conversions</title>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <script src="../../testFile_files/jquery.min.js.download"></script>

        <script src="conversions.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="output"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var strName = "";
var strDoubloons = "";

$(document).ready( function(strName) {
    var strAskName = "Arrr, what is your Pirate name?";
    var strDefaultName = "Captain Blackbeard";
    strName = prompt(strAskName, strDefaultName);  
    return strName;
});

$(document).ready( function(strDoubloons) {
    var strAskDoubloons = "Arr, how many gold doubloons have ye'plundered?";
    var strDefaultDoubloons = "100";
    strDoubloons = prompt(strAskDoubloons, strDefaultDoubloons);
    return strDoubloons;
});

$(document).ready ( function(strName, strDoubloons){    
    intDoubloons = parseInt(strDoubloons);
    intProfit = intDoubloons * 287;

    var message = "Arr! I, " +  strName + " have plundered" + strDoubloons + 
" gold doubloons and sold them for a total of $" + intProfit + " time to buy me a new cannon!";
    var display = document.getElementById("output");
    display.textContent = message;
});
```

Comment: Remove the parameters from your functions. You don’t need them. Your functions are getting called with undefined arguments.

Comment: i mean.. you know what `$(document).ready` does right? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ready/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would do it like this https://jsfiddle.net/n7j5xfsf/

Place all the code in one document ready call, there is no point that wrap every function with the document ready call.

```
var strName = "";
var strDoubloons = "";

$(document).ready( 
 function() {
    var strAskName = "Arrr, what is your Pirate name?";
    var strDefaultName = "Captain Blackbeard";
    strName = prompt(strAskName, strDefaultName);  

    var strAskDoubloons = "Arr, how many gold doubloons have ye'plundered?";
    var strDefaultDoubloons = "100";
    strDoubloons = prompt(strAskDoubloons, strDefaultDoubloons);

    intDoubloons = parseInt(strDoubloons);
    intProfit = intDoubloons * 287;

    var message = "Arr! I, " +  strName + " have plundered" + strDoubloons + 
" gold doubloons and sold them for a total of $" + intProfit + " time to buy me a new cannon!";
    var display = document.getElementById("output");
    display.textContent = message;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad practice to use global variables like this. Better spearate tour code into functions that get and return values and have as little side effects as possible. This way it is much easier to reason about the code. As for why it didn't work before is because you replaced the `onready` event handler of the document every time and it only executed the last.

```js
function getName() {
  var strAskName = "Arrr, what is your Pirate name?";
  var strDefaultName = "Captain Blackbeard";
  return prompt(strAskName, strDefaultName);
}

function getDoubloons() {
  var strAskDoubloons = "Arr, how many gold doubloons have ye'plundered?";
  var strDefaultDoubloons = "100";
  return prompt(strAskDoubloons, strDefaultDoubloons);
}

function printInfo(strName, strDoubloons) {
  intDoubloons = parseInt(strDoubloons);
  intProfit = intDoubloons * 287;

  var message = "Arr! I, " + strName + " have plundered " + strDoubloons +
    " gold doubloons and sold them for a total of $" + intProfit + " time to buy me a new cannon!";
  var display = document.getElementById("output");
  display.textContent = message;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  printInfo(getName(), getDoubloons());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

  <title>Conversions</title>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <script src="../../testFile_files/jquery.min.js.download"></script>

  <script src="conversions.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="output"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Write the functions outside of your document.ready and call them inside

```
function func1(strName) {
    var strAskName = "Arrr, what is your Pirate name?";
    var strDefaultName = "Captain Blackbeard";
    strName = prompt(strAskName, strDefaultName);  
    return strName;
}



function func2(strDoubloons) {
    var strAskDoubloons = "Arr, how many gold doubloons have ye'plundered?";
    var strDefaultDoubloons = "100";
    strDoubloons = prompt(strAskDoubloons, strDefaultDoubloons);
    return strDoubloons;
}

function func3(strName, strDoubloons){    
    intDoubloons = parseInt(strDoubloons);
    intProfit = intDoubloons * 287;

    var message = "Arr! I, " +  strName + " have plundered" + strDoubloons + 
" gold doubloons and sold them for a total of $" + intProfit + " time to buy me a new cannon!";
    var display = document.getElementById("output");
    display.textContent = message;
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    // Call your start up function
});
```